# show list of slides in AucTeX

Tags: beamer, auctex, reftex

While editing beamer in Emacs with AUCTeX and RefTeX, how can I make the `C-c =` command list the frames instead the sections? Is it possible to customize the outline command?

Answer (score 3):

The key binding <kbd>C-c =</kbd> is provided by RefTeX and not by AUCTeX.  <kbd>C-h k C-c =</kbd> returns:

> <kbd>C-c =</kbd> runs the command `reftex-toc` (found in reftex-mode-map), which is
> an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘reftex-toc.el’.
>
> It is bound to <kbd>C-c =</kbd>,   .
>
> (reftex-toc &optional REBUILD REUSE)
>
> Show the table of contents for the current document. When called with
> a raw `C-u` prefix, rescan the document first.

In order to tell RefTeX about new sectioning commands you have to customize the variable `reftex-section-levels`:

> `reftex-section-levels` is a variable defined in ‘reftex-vars.el’. Its
> value is shown below.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Documentation: Commands and levels used for defining sections in the
> document. This is an alist with each element like `(COMMAND-NAME . LEVEL)`. The car of each cons cell is the name of the section macro
> (without the backslash).  The cdr is a number indicating its level.  A
> negative level means the same level as the positive value, but the
> section will never get a number.  The cdr may also be a function which
> will be called to after the section-re matched to determine the level.
> This list is also used for promotion and demotion of sectioning
> commands. If you are using a document class which has several sets of
> sectioning commands, promotion only works correctly if this list is
> sorted first by set, then within each set by level.  The promotion
> commands always select the nearest entry with the correct new level.

Suppose your .tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
    \item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.
    \item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
    \item<1-> But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
      number not in the first $p$ numbers.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Do <kbd>M-x customize-variable RET reftex-section-levels RET</kbd> and add values for `frametitle` and `framesubtitle` like this:

[image]

And hit `Apply and Save`.  Now open your .tex file and try it again.

Comment: This works like a charm.  If possible, I would be greatly thankful for an alternative solution as emacs lisp code snippet for the `.emacs`.